# How to customize the UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone

I am using a datepicker. Now, what i have to do is to show day, date, month and year only. Is there any way to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot customize the UIDatePicker instead you can change the mode it appears
Try any of the following as per your requirement

1. UIDatePickerModeTime,
   // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)
2. UIDatePickerModeDate,
   // Displays month, minute, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)
3. UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)

4.UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
// Displays hour and minute (e.g. 1 | 53)

Happy Coding.