# Can i customize UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uidatepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize the UIDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022218/how-to-customize-the-uidatepicker)

I need to customize UIDatePicker as we do support a variety of date formats like
 `dd-MM-yyyy`, `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`, `dd-MM`.

E.g. in "date and time" picker mode, there is no roller for year part in picker.Hence the provided picker modes are not sufficient.

Is there any way to customize a datepicker for the desired formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!
You cannot do this with `UIDatePicker` as it only supports 4 date formats, according to the [UIDatePicker Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html); however you can with a `UIPickerView`.

You will need to need to implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods and provide them with a data source, just like you would with a `UITableView`:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView*)thePickerView {
   return /* # of columns you need */;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return /* # of rows per component */;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return /* date source/string/title for the row */;
}
```

Reference: [here](http://divya-ioscoder.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/uipicker-iphone-sdk-populated-with-year.html)

Answer (score 1):

A `UIDatePicker` supports the four `datePickerMode` constants detailed in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html). You can't provide custom date formats. However, depending on your application and requirements you could just use a standard picker view: I've done this where I only need to display a list of months.